# How to see specific statistics of branch in git?

Tags: git

There is some git repository, called Foo. Foo repository has `refactor` branch, which contains refactored code. Is there some method to retrieve such information from branch as:

1. Count of deleted lines
2. Count of inserted lines
3. Size of deleted symbols
4. Size of inserted symbols

Comment: This analogy is quite imperfect, but you've just asked, in effect: "what's the difference between a car, how many more seats does it have?"  The key is that we're missing the *other half of the comparison*. Are we to compare to another car? If so, which one? To get an answer in Git, you need to specify *commits*, and "a branch" picks *one* commit, but not the *other* commit. If you generalize it, "a branch" picks the tip commit of the branch *plus* every commit *reachable from* the tip, and now we have *too many* commits. You need to pick exactly two for `git diff`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `git diff --stat Foo..master` if you didn't performed any backmerges to Foo, or `git diff --stat <branch root> HEAD`.